# I was set up in a sting

Tags: meaning-in-context, meaning

I read someone's story and she said: "Then I was set up in a sting by the same woman who got me started.

I was wondering what has just happened !! .. What is she implying ? I couldn't understand by looking up the word "sting"

Comment: For a quick answer type **sting-operation** into the Search Q&A box. top right. 8 Answers.

Comment: See [The Sting (movie)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0070735/?ref_=nv_sr_1) for background.

Comment: And then watch The Sting (movie).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it refers to ***[sting](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sting)*** meaning:

> - (Law) slang a trap set up by the police to entice a person to commit a crime and thereby produce evidence.

Probably implying that she had 'framed' him.

(The Free Dictionary)

Comment: A "sting" is just as likely to be a criminal activity as it is a law-enforcement one.

Comment: @HotLicks *Sting-operations* can be set up by newspapers to entrap someone, often a politician, into behaving injudiciously. Several years ago Sven Eriksson, the then Swedish coach to the England football team was approached by a middle-eastern-looking individual, who was a reporter purporting to be a billionaire Sheikh. He claimed to be in negotiations to buy the Aston Villa football team and wanted Eriksson as coach. SE embarrassingly revealed details of his views about many of his England players, and the story was all over the newspapers. It became known as *The Fake Sheikh affair*.

Comment: @WS2 - But it should be noted that, as in the movie *The Sting*, a sting is not always set up "to produce evidence", but may be instead used to defraud someone of money.  Basically, a "sting" is the climactic step of an elaborate "con" -- "confidence game".